# Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to access a static image to use within an inline `backgroundImage` property within React. Unfortunately, I've run up dry on how to do this.

Generally, I thought you just did as follows:

```
import Background from '../images/background_image.png';

var sectionStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "400px",
  backgroundImage: "url(" + { Background } + ")"
};

class Section extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section style={ sectionStyle }>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```

This works for `<img>` tags. Can someone explain the difference between the two?

Example:

`<img src={ Background } />` works just fine.

Thank you!

Answer (score 794, accepted):

The curly braces inside backgroundImage property are wrong.

Probably you are using webpack along with image files loader, so Background should be already a String:
`backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")"`

You can also use ES6 string templates as below to achieve the same effect:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
```

Comment: I should have added that to my question. I do have a width and height set (100% / 400px respectively). The issue arising is due to how react handles static images I believe.

Comment: Should one escape the '(", ')' and whitespace characters in the Background variable before concatenation as per https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/syndata.html#value-def-uri ?

Comment: Full syntax should look like this: `style={{backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")"}}`

Comment: just to expand @mike's comment, you need double curly braces because one is for React to enter is JS mode and one is to denote the new object.

Comment: I am getting the error 'Section' is defined but never used' after giving this
import Background from './background.jpg';
var sectionStyle = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "400px",
  backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
};

class Section extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section style={ sectionStyle }>
      </section>
    );
  }
}

Comment: +1 to @mike answer. The accepted answer throws off my linter and keeps giving me grief with rando red squiggly lines that have been driving me crazy all day.

Answer (score 99):

Inline style to set any image full screen:

```
style={{  
  backgroundImage: "url(" + "https://images.pexels.com/photos/34153/pexels-photo.jpg?auto=compress&cs=tinysrgb&h=350" + ")",
  backgroundPosition: 'center',
  backgroundSize: 'cover',
  backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat'
}}
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch, this is what I was looking for

Comment: import Background from '../images/background_image.png'; Followed by the answer here did solve my problem, together is the best answer right now.

Comment: import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import style from './style.module.css';

import authBg from '../../assets/Auth/authBg.png';

const Auth = () => {
    return (
        <div
            style={{  
            backgroundImage: "url(" + authBg + ")",
            backgroundPosition: 'center',
            backgroundSize: 'cover',
            backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
            height: '100vh',
            width: '100vw'
            }}>
            daf
        </div>
    
    );
}

export default Auth

Answer (score 71):

If you are using ES5 -

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")"
```

If you are using ES6 -

```
backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
```

Basically removing unnecessary curly braces while adding value to backgroundImage property works will work.

Comment: For me in ES6 it was `backgroundImage: \`url("${Background}")\``, as your ES6 example didn't work for me.

Comment: Hello Bharad, how would you go about it if you want to add more than one background image. Say for two images how would you do this? Thanks

Comment: @S.. Thanks, that helped me. I was stuck.

Answer (score 38):

You can also bring the image into the component by using the `require()` function.

```html
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(require("images/img.svg"))` }}>
```

**Note the two sets of curly brackets**. The first set is for entering react mode and the second is for denoting object

Comment: What if the image path is a web URL instead of a local path? Something like `https://images.com/myimage.png`

Comment: Ok I understand, when using web-based URL. I should just write `url(https://images.com/myimage.png)`

Answer (score 22):

It works for me:

```
  import Background from '../images/background_image.png';
    
  <div className=...
       style={{
              background: `url(${Background})`,
            }}
    >...</div>
```

Answer (score 18):

For me what worked is having it like this

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${require("./resources/img/banners/3.jpg")})` }}
```

Answer (score 15):

You can use Template literals (enclosed with back-tick: `...`) instead. For `backgroundImage` property like this:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
```

Answer (score 12):

For a `local` File in case of ReactJS.
Try

```
import Image from "../../assets/image.jpg";

<div
style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(' + Image + ')', backgroundSize: 'auto' }}
>Hello
</div>
```

This is the case of `ReactJS` with inline styling where `Image` is a local file that you must have imported with a path.

Comment: The properties are backgroundImage and backgroundSize in jsx

Answer (score 6):

Change line 6 of your code from

```
  backgroundImage: "url(" + { Background} + ")"
```

to

```
  backgroundImage: "url(" + { Background.src } + ")"
```

and it will work.

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(require("path/image.ext"))` }}
```

Answer (score 4):

Sometimes your SVG will be inlined by React so you need quotes around it:

```
backgroundImage: `url("${Background}")`
```

otherwise it's invalid CSS and the browser dev tools will not show that you've set background-image at all.

Comment: thanks, tried a few on this page and this answer worked for me

Answer (score 3):

updated to 17.05.22
instead:

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + { Background } + ")"
```

do:

```
backgroundImage: "url(" + Background + ")"
```

Answer (score 2):

try this it worked in my case

```
backgroundImage: `url("${Background}")`
```

Answer (score 2):

For ES6, please use

```
backgroundImage: `url("${Background}")
```

Comment: You are missing the endind tick `\`` in `url(${Background})\``.

Answer (score 1):

1. Copy the image to the React Component's folder where you want to see it.
2. Copy the following code:

```html
<div className="welcomer" style={{ backgroundImage: url(${myImage}) }}></div>
```

3. Give a height to your `.welcomer` using CSS so that you can see your image in the desired size.

Answer (score 1):

```
import React, { PureComponent } from 'react'
import logo from './logo.png';

class Home extends PureComponent {
    render() {
        return (
            <div>
                 <div
                    style={{
                        backgroundImage: `url("https://www.nicesnippets.com/image/imgpsh_fullsize.png")`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', width: '800px', height: '250px', color: 'blue'
                    }}>
                        Nice Snippets
                </div>
                    <hr />
                    <div
                        style={{
                            backgroundImage: `url(${logo})`, backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat', width: '100%', height: '250px', color: 'blue'
                        }}>
                        Nice Snippets
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
}

export default Home
```

Comment: backgroundImage: `url("https://www.nicesnippets.com/image/imgpsh_fullsize.png")`
or  backgroundImage: `url(${logo})`

Answer (score 0):

Just add required to file or url

```
<div style={
   {
      backgroundImage: `url(${require("./path_local")})`,      
   }
}
>
```

Or set in css base64 image like

```
div {
  background:
    url('data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhZQBhAPcAACQgDxMFABsHABYJABsLA')
    no-repeat
    left center;
}
```

You can use https://www.base64-image.de/ for convert

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with by adding backticks on whole url

`style={{backgroundImage:url(${val.image || 'http://max-themes.net/demos/grandtour/upload/Tokyo_Dollarphotoclub_72848283-copy-700x466.jpg'} ) }}`

Answer (score 0):

If you are using **webpack** you need to edit **webpack.config.js** and
add this into it

```js
module: {
  rules: [
 {
      test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,

     dependency: { not: ['url'] },
      use: [
        {
          loader: 'url-loader',
          options: {
            limit: 8192,
          },
        },
      ],
    },
  ],
}
```

if you use **file-loader** for rendering images you need to delete that like below:

```js
    {
       test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif)$/i,
       loader: 'file-loader',
    },
```

and in your css file instead of using **background-image** use **background** instead:

```css
background: url(Background);
```

for more information about webpack with images see this also:
https://v4.webpack.js.org/loaders/url-loader/

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me

```html
style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${require("../assets/pet4.jpeg").default})` }}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to use backgroundImage: url() to display an image you have two ways

1- if the image path include spaces or special chars use this
backgroundImage: `url("${props.img}")`,

2- if the image path doesn't include any spaces or special chars use this backgroundImage: `url(${props.img})`,

Answer (score -2):

You Can try usimg

```
backgroundImage: url(process.env.PUBLIC_URL + "/      assets/image_location")
```

Comment: This is not recommended since it will prevent webpack from knowing the asset. This will end in a cache miss if the react app is opened offline.