# Inline style is not working ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to learn React. Why can you not use style inside of a return inside of a component?

The Error:

> The `style` prop expects a mapping from style properties to values,
>   not a string. For example, style={{marginRight: spacing + 'em'}} when
>   using JSX. This DOM node was rendered by `Home`.

```
<div className="single_slide" style="background-image: url(../images/WinterCalling_2016.jpg);">
```

I have also tried this also:

```
<div className="single_slide" style={{background-image: 'url(../images/WinterCalling_2016.jpg)'}}>
```

or

```
<div className="single_slide" style={{background-image: url(../images/WinterCalling_2016.jpg)}}>
```

Any help with this syntax would be greatly appreciated. Other people posted they change style to say styles but that did not seem to work either.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

**From [DOC](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html#style)**:

> In React, inline styles are not specified as a string. Instead they
>   are specified with an object whose key is the camelCased version of
>   the style name, and whose value is the style's value, usually a
>   string.

So instead of `background-image` use `backgroundImage`.

**For example:**

```
padding-top      --->     paddingTop

padding-left     --->     paddingLeft

margin-right     --->     marginRight

...
```

> How to specify the inline style?

We need to pass a object to style attribute which will contains all the values in form of key-value pair.

Like this:

```
<div 
    style={{
       backgroundImage: 'url(../images/WinterCalling_2016.jpg)', 
       marginTop: 20}}
>
```

**Update:**

We can use [template literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals) to pass a variable inside url, like this:

```
<div style={{backgroundImage: `url(${image1})`}}>
```

Comment: Note for visitors - typos within your style declaration can cause the `style` attribute to not even appear on render... which can cause it to appear `style` is not working...

Comment: @cale_b can you point out the typo please? will correct that.

Comment: Sorry - not saying _you_ had typos - saying that if you _have_ a typo, it won't work.  I found this Q&A because styles were not appearing at all, and discovered that I had a typo in my code: `url(${image1});` - the stray semicolon made it an invalid value, and since there was only one style property, the `style` attribute didn't even appear on the element....

Answer (score 3):

React follow the camelcase convention so you have to change `background-image` to `backgroundImage` instead.

For more info, see [the documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/dom-elements.html).

Comment: `url` accepts a string, so I don't think that would work. You can use string templates instead, like the one in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles

Comment: To be somewhat more clear - _javascript_ follows the camelcase convention, and React is javascript, so it in turn follows the camelCase convention....

Answer (score 2):

If you want to use the style property, please provide a JavaScript dictionary object. However, the style key for `background-image` is `backgroundImage`.

```
<div 
    className="single_slide" 
    style={{backgroundImage: 'url(../images/WinterCalling_2016.jpg)'}}
>
```

Comment: @DavidBrierton Yes you can do that. Depending on what's the webpack resource loader you are using, you might get a URL of base64 data or a static file url.

Comment: @DavidBrierton and you will need to use the template literal as Mayank Shukla's answer shows.

Answer (score -2):

Did you try wrapping background-image in quotes?

i.e.

```
<div className="single_slide" style={{'background-image': 'url(../images/WinterCalling_2016.jpg)'}}></div>
```

This seems to work for me (at least, when testing with the background-color property; I don't have an image on hand to test with for background-image)

Answer (score -3):

or you can use '!important' with this ....like "background-color:red!important"
Note: And call your js in footer .Because sometimes js reacts first when we call that in header.so call your 'js' in footer.

```
<div class="yourclass" style="background-color:red;"  >your div</div>
```

style="background-color:red;"

Comment: Its not nice presented what you want to say. And furthermore I have the impression it don't add new content to this question.