# Change state but don't change style Reactjs

Tags: css, reactjs, state

it's weird when I try to change the style of this section by changing state when user mouseOver button. The content of h1 tag is changed but style of the section isn't. Could someone help me on that?

```
    export class Jumbotron extends Component {

    constructor (props) {
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      style: {
        backgroundImage: 'none'
      }
    }

    this.handleSubjectMouseOver = this.handleSubjectMouseOver.bind(this)
  }

  handleSubjectMouseOver (bg) {
    console.log(bg)
    this.setState({
      style: {
        backgroundImage: bg
      }
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <section className="jumbotron container" style=
    {this.state.style}>
      <h1>{this.state.style}</h1>
      <div className="jumbotron-content">
        <h2 style={{marginBottom: 3, marginTop: 40}}>Learning is fun with 
        LIVE</h2>
        <div style={{marginLeft: 10}}>Body ........</div>
        <div style={{marginBottom: 20, marginTop: 80}}
             className="subjects-title">TOP CLASSES, TUTORIAL & TIPS TO EXCEL IN:
        </div>
        <div className="subjects" style={{backgroundImage: this.state.background}}>
          <RaisedButton label="MATH" secondary onMouseMove={() => { this.handleSubjectMouseOver(mathBg) }} />
          <RaisedButton label="PHYSICS" secondary onMouseMove={() => { this.handleSubjectMouseOver(physicBg) }} />
          <RaisedButton label="CHEMISTRY" secondary onMouseMove={() => { this.handleSubjectMouseOver(chemistryBg) }} />
          <RaisedButton label="BIOLOGY" secondary onMouseMove={() => { this.handleSubjectMouseOver(biologyBg) }} />
          <RaisedButton label="COMP SCIENCE" secondary
                        onMouseMove={() => { this.handleSubjectMouseOver(computerBg) }} />
        </div>
      </div>
    </section>
  }
```

Comment: I had this issue yesterday, Instead of changing the CSS directly. Have your CSS have two different classes, and on event changes, toggle these classes. Also, make sure you've conditionals that check for state changes, are you doing that in your code?

Comment: in my case, I don't have any conditional rendering. because the number of the background image is dynamic. I can't use classes here. :(

Comment: Could you post a little bit more detailed code so I can understand where the problem is?

Comment: list of RaiseButton is dynamic from db.

Comment: style={{'backgroundImage': 'url('+this.state.background+')'}} use this one if background contains image path

Comment: Ok I think I know what's wrong I'll post it as an answer.

Comment: Please let me know it will help you or not

Comment: `this.handleSubjectMouseOver(mathBg)` :  `mathBg` is undefined

Comment: You are passing  undefined vars ( unless that was just an example ) ^^

Comment: @SantoshShinde your solution worked. Could you post as an answer and explain more the detail about this. Thanks.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the following line in place of setting background image

```
style={{'backgroundImage': 'url('+this.state.background+')'}}
```

To read more in details about this to [here](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-values-3/#urls) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles).

And also check the css-loader issues with webpack to [here](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/css-loader/issues/256).

Hopes this will help you!

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing typically wrong with the code, it's just that your event isn't firing because of one simple reason.

```
<RaisedButton onMouseMove={() => { this.handleSubjectMouseOver(mathBg) }} />
```

Here, `RaisedButton` isn't a native DOM element, it totally depends on how you defined it. Here, the `mouseOver` event that you supplied is simply a property, and doesn't count as an event. To fix this, you need to pass an event to a native DOM element, wrap your component around a div and pass the event to it, like this.

```
<div className="raisedButtonClass" onMouseMove={someFunction}>
     <RaisedButton ......./>
</div>
```

I hope this fixes your problem :)

Comment: I can make sure this event is fired because it logged and value of tag p change when I mouseOver this component. ^^

Comment: the problem is css: [backgroundImage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-image)

Comment: he is passing an anonymous function so it should work