# Background Image not being displayed

Tags: css, reactjs

I am setting my background image on CDM but `document.body.style={mainBg}` does not set the background image as I expected and the console statement below it prints out an empty string. Can anyone help me figure out what I am doing wrong?

```
const mainBg = {
 backgroundImage: 'url("../img/background.jpg")',
 backgroundPosition: 'center',
 backgroundRepeat: 'no-repeat',
 backgroundAttachment: 'fixed',
 backgroundSize: 'cover',
};


class Home extends Component {
 componentDidMount() {
    console.log(mainBg);
    document.body.style = {mainBg};
    console.log(document.body.style.backgroundImage)
 }
}
```

**EDIT**: I am looking to set the background image for the body.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `<body>` element sits outside the React.js app, (which is usually the case), then, rather than using React.js to set the body styles, you can use vanilla javascript.

An up-to-date (2018) way to do this would be to use the *new* **CSS Typed-Object Model (CSSOM)** which will allow you to loop through `mainBg` and add each property and value to the `attributeStyleMap` property for the element `document.body`.

**Working Example:**

```js
const mainBg = {
  width: '100%',
  height: '100vh',
  'background-image': `url("../img/background.jpg")`,
  'background-position': 'center',
  'background-repeat': 'no-repeat',
  'background-attachment': 'fixed',
  'background-size': 'cover',
  };


for (const declaration in mainBg) {
    
    document.body.attributeStyleMap.set(declaration, mainBg[declaration]);
    console.log('<body> has the declaration: ' + declaration + ': ' + mainBg[declaration] + ';');
}
```

---

[Further Reading about the **CSS Typed-Object Model (CSSOM)**](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2018/03/cssom)

Answer (score 1):

You should try like this

```js
import Background from '../images/background_image.png';

var bckImg = {
  width: "100%",
  height: "400px",
  backgroundImage: `url(${Background})`
};

class Section extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <section style={ bckImg }>
      </section>
    );
  }
}
```