# Setting the background in reactJS

Tags: css, reactjs

i'm new to ReactJs and my question may seem stupid to many of you, but i have a problem with setting the background. My React code  is:

```
<header className="masthead ttt">
          <div className="overlay"></div>
          <div className="container">
            <div className="row">
              <div className="col-lg-8 col-md-10 mx-auto">
                <div className="site-heading">
                  <h1>Blog Name</h1>
                  <span className="subheading">blablablablabla</span>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </header>
```

So basically i'm trying to set an image as background in my header , so i created a class .ttt and modified it to my css that way :

```
.ttt{
  background-image: url("../img/home-bg.jpg");
}
```

And finally here's the way the folders are set :

[image]

Am i doing anything wrong in my code ? Or there's another way of doing things in ReactJS! 
Thanks!

Comment: Ar you getting any errors in your console?

Comment: No i'm not getting any error.

Comment: hmmm. Can you please replicate what you have so far in codepen or jsfiddle? Ill check it out.

Comment: Just try `/img/home-bg.jpg` , as it's already in public folder. And assuming, you installed the react using `create-react-app`

Comment: I tried but didn't work and yes i installed using the create-react-app command. The thing is when put my background-image into the masthead class it works fine but if i try to move it to the ttt class it doesn't work!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So far what I understood from your problem is that you are not getting the image on the front-end. While checking it through developer options it must be pointing you to a blank div at the top of the screen. 
*If that's the case then it is because that every background image needs some size to be displayed.*

You can either give **width and height** or you can give **background-size** property as follows:

```
.ttt{
    background-image: url("../img/home-bg.jpg");
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;  // giving height is not compulsary but just for good practice.
}
```

OR

```
.ttt{
    background-image: url("../img/home-bg.jpg");
    background-size: 100% 100%; // First value: {Width}   Second value: {Height}
}
```

This would resolve your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Use inline css in javascript like this:

```
import Background from '../img/home-bg.jpg'; // make sure path is correct

<header className="masthead" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Background})` }} >
```

[ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles) Be mindful of using `backgroundImage` instead of `background-image`

Answer (score 0):

Working for me

```js
<div className="drag-dashboard" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${config.DESTINATION_MEDIA_CDN+ "assets/icons_skining/upload_placeholder_skining.png"})`}}>
                                   </div>
```