# Issue with displaying background image in a div with REACT

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

I am trying to display a background image in a `div` and though it works fine for a standard `img` tag I can't make it work for the `div`.
What am I doing wrong?
Below is where I import the image:

```
import imgPackage from '../img/package.png';
```

And below is the 2 pieces of code - `div` doesn't display anything and `img` works fine.

```
<div
  style={{
  height: '50px',
  width: '50px',
  backgroundImage: 'url(${ imgPackage })'
  }}
/>

<img src={imgPackage} alt="Smiley face" height="42" width="42" />
```

In the div `backgroundImage` I tried the following and none worked

```
backgroundImage: 'url(${ imgPackage })'
backgroundImage: 'url('+{ imgPackage }+')'
backgroundImage: 'url(../img/package.png)'
```

What am I doing wrong? 
Thanks!

Comment: Duplicate Issue
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're trying to use a template literal but you're using single quotes instead of back-ticks.

> Template literals are enclosed by the back-tick (` `)  (grave accent) character instead of double or single quotes. Template literals can contain placeholders. These are indicated by the dollar sign and curly braces (${expression}).
>
> — [Template literals on MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

```
<div
  style={{
    ...,
    backgroundImage: `url(${imgPackage})`
  }}
/>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using this. on single quotes you cant use ${} syntax. it can be used with `` back tick

```
backgroundImage: `url(${ imgPackage })`
backgroundImage: 'url('+ imgPackage +')'
```

Answer (score 1):

Any of your tries are wrong. Following variants will work after some changes:

If you prefer ES6 template literals you should use back-ticks quotes for them:

```
backgroundImage: `url(${ imgPackage })`;
```

If you prefer plain strings no need to add extra single quotes inside `url()`:

```
backgroundImage: 'url( + { imgPackage } + )';
```

This case might working with appropriate url-loader from you webpack etc. Consider to use 2 examples above.

```
backgroundImage: 'url(../img/package.png)'
```