# div with image is not showing in d-flex flex-column

Tags: html, css, reactjs, bootstrap-4, flexbox

The structure is:

```
<div className="d-flex flex-column">
  <div>
     Text
  </div>
  <div style={{ backgroundImage: 'url(...)' }}>
  </div>
</div>
```

Url is working. Div exists, but image not showing
When I use flex-row it works

Comment: Give the div height and width to see if the image appears

Comment: @Andus it appears, if i do width 100% height 100%, it cuts the height of image

Comment: div cannot visually seen if there's no explicit height/width itself or in its children alone, since you see your image now, you can use `object-fit: contain` or `object-fit: cover` to solve that, according to your preference

Comment: May be this could help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles

Answer (score 0):

add two more styles
`background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;`

```html
<div class="d-flex flex-column">
  <div>
     Text
  </div>
  <div style="background: url(https://www.google.com/images/branding/googlelogo/1x/googlelogo_color_272x92dp.png);background-size: contain;background-repeat: no-repeat;">
  <br><br><br><br>
  </div>
</div>
```