# How to change background image of div?

Tags: javascript, html

This is my code:

```
<div style = {{ backgroundImage: "url(img.jpg)" }} className="card">
    <h3>{character.name}</h3>
</div>
```

This code doesnt work. Output just white color

Comment: That's not valid HTML. If you're using a framework, be sure to include its tag.

Comment: @rrakhlin please provide more detail and code regarding the question

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles)

Comment: @rrakhlin provided you the generic solution which will work irrespective of your any js framework

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${require("img.jpg")})` }} className="card">
    <h3>{character.name}</h3>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Providing you the generic solution which will work in any javascript frameworks.

HTML

```
<div id="parentDiv" className="card">
    <h3>XYZ </h3>
</div>
```

JS

```
document.getElementByID('parentDiv').style.backgroundImage = "url('your_image_name.png')";
```