# Need to set background image from API response in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, reactjs

Need to set a background image from API response in ReactJS

Sample code:

```
useEffect(() => {
axios.get(`https://apiaddress=${API_KEY}`)
.then(res=>{
    console.log(res);
    setRetrieved(res.data);
    console.log(retrieved);
  
})
.catch(err=>{
    console.log(err)
})
     return(
    <div ClassName="home" style={{backgroundImage:`url({retrieved.imageurl}{/*or 
    any other var of type string*/}), width: 1920, height: 1080 } </div>
```

Also tried to save the retrieved image in a variable, working fine but the image (which is coming in response) is not rendered as background.

Answer (score 2):

Update your style prop

```
style={{backgroundImage: `url('${retrieved.imageurl}')`}}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this way if your image comes from an API:

```
return(
<div ClassName="home" style={{backgroundImage:"url(" + retrieved.imageurl + ")", width: 1920, height: 1080 } </div>
```

For my answer, I referred to this code answer:
[Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles)