# How to crop and center an image with CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm still a beginner with CSS and I'm not able to adjust an image as I was request in zeplin.

The original image is quite tall, and in the zeplin the image is cut and shows only the center, with the model in the pic. As you can see in the image below

[image]

Can you tell me how to adjust the image in the same way as it is in Zeplin? I put my code into [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-fast-6sj1l?file=/src/App.js).

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Art1 from "./images/art_home_1.png";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="images">
        <img src={Art1} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  height: 720px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Thank you in advance for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Onother option is to set the image as a [`background-image`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles) so you can use the css propertys like `background-position` to align the image.

```
<div className="images" style={{ backgroundImage: `url(${Art1})` }}></div>
```

```
background-position: bottom;
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can position your image `relative` and then move it as you wish. This should be quite accurate to the image you provided above:

```js
import "./styles.css";
import Art1 from "./images/art_home_1.png";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
      <div className="images">
        <img src={Art1} alt="" />
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

```css
.App {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  text-align: center;
}

.images {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  height: 720px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

img {
  position: relative;
  top: -350px;
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get rid of the div surrounding the img, and just use  object-fit property to make the image cover the available space. It is responsive and much better practice than dealing with position absolute.
your app.js will look something like this:

```
import "./styles.css";
import Art1 from "./images/art_home_1.png";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>Hello CodeSandbox</h1>
        <img src={Art1} alt="" className="images" />
    </div>
  );
}
```

Styles.css:

```
.images {
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 720px;
  height: 720px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

Your image will be responsive, it will be full on small screens and you can adjust the max-width property of **images** className to get your desired output for bigger screens.