# How to import images into CSS Modules?

Tags: css, reactjs, webpack, react-css-modules

I'm creating a website(creating using React). so I want to add a full-screen image for the Home page. I'm using CSS module. when importing an image into the module.css it's not rendered. How can I fix this. Here is my code. I'm importing this (scr => assets folder)

[codesandbox-link](https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-burnell-ndkzj?file=/src/App.module.css)

**Home.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import styles from '../styles/Home.module.css'
 
const Home = () => {
    
    return (
        <div className={styles.Hero} ></div>       
                             
        
    )
}

export default Home
```

**Home.module.css**

```
.Hero {
  background-image: url(../assets/hero.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
}
```

Comment: Hello @AjeetShah here is codesandbox link https://codesandbox.io/s/stupefied-burnell-ndkzj?file=/src/App.module.css

Comment: Look at the code in the browser, what's the class name of the div? Should it be `Hero`, instead?

Comment: I request you to go through this question to get better insight https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles

Answer (score 3):

It is CSS issue, your `div`, which is supposed to show the image in the background, has no `height` and `width`:

Background image is loading perfectly after adding below styles:

**Global CSS (styles.css):**

```css
html,
body,
#root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

**App.module.css:**

```css
.Hero {
  background-image: url(./assets/hero.jpg);
  background-position: center;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}
```

and in `App.js`:

```
import styles from "./App.module.css";

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div style={{ width: "100%", height: "100%" }}>
      <div className={styles.Hero}></div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

I am not good at CSS. So, this may not be the perfect way to handle stylings (height / width). So, you may improve it. Here is the full [code](https://github.com/ajeetshah/so-image-question)*.

---

As [mentioned](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-images-fonts-and-files/) in docs, with webpack, you can load images in CSS as:

```
.Logo {
  background-image: url(./logo.png);
}
```

Webpack finds all relative module references in CSS (they start with ./) and replaces them with the final paths from the compiled bundle.

*I provided full code as the image was not showing in codesandbox, but showing at my local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Try this in a non-sandbox environment. The way you have imported className is fine.
I have a feeling sandbox is not reflecting it properly.
You can also try -

`content:url(<path to image>);`

in the className instead of background-image:url

Answer (score 0):

I used the background in color and succeeded but the image didn't, you can import the image into App.js

```
 import image from "./url";

 return (
  <img src={image} alt="" />
 )
```