# Can't put bg image in react.js

Tags: reactjs, web

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Pk1Hd.png)

import React from 'react'
import pic from './pic2.png'
const Header = () => {
return (

```
<div className="container-fluid">
<div className="row text-center align-items-center ">

        <div className="bg col-md-6 ">
            <div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/pic.jpg)` }}>
            
              </div>

        </div>
        <div className=" col-6">
              <h1>Login</h1>

              <form className='loginf'>
                
                    <label className='pt-4'> Username </label> <br></br>
                    <input type='text'className='form-rounded p-1' placeholder=' username'/>
                    <br></br>   <br></br>
                    <label> Password </label>   <br></br>
                    <input type='password' className='form-rounded p-1' placeholder=' password'/>
              
            
              </form>
              <br></br>           
              <button className='btn btn-basic form-rounded2'>Login </button>


        </div>
</div>
</div>
```

)
}

export default Header

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You have imported a picture, so u can try use object {pic}, not a link to picture

Instead *<div style={{ backgroundImage: `url(/pic.jpg)` }}>*
Try: <div style={{ backgroundImage:  **``url(${pic})`** }}>

Similar issue: [Setting a backgroundImage With React Inline Styles](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39195687/setting-a-backgroundimage-with-react-inline-styles)

Comment: still no result